# Crear enum en java

Tags: java

Deseo hacer un mantenimiento de una tabla en java soy un desarrollador C# quisiera saber si esto se puede hacer en java

```
public enum AlmacenStatus : int
{
    Activo = 1,
    Inactivo = 0
}
```

He logrado hacer lo siguiente

```
public enum ArticuloStatus  {
   ACTIVO, INACTIVO
}
```

Mi intención es guardar 1 ó 0 según el enum que seleccione

Saludos!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

El formato del `enum` en java es un poco mas simple, y tiene sus restricciones. Los elementos del `enum` se numeran automáticamente de 0 en adelante. Para tu caso seria:

```
public enum ArticuloStatus  {
  INACTIVO, ACTIVO
}
```

Y puedes accederlo como:

```
ArticuloStatus.ACTIVO.ordinal(); //0 (int)
ArticuloStatus.INACTIVO.ordinal(); //1 (int)

ArticuloStatus.ACTIVO; // "ACTIVO" (String)
ArticuloStatus.INACTIVO; // "INACTIVO" (String)
```

Una manera mas completa es definir un `enum` con valores arbitrarios, aunque para el caso puntual, la opción anterior lo mantiene simple. Incluso se pueden definir métodos adicionales para operar con los valores del `enum`:

```
public enum ArticuloStatus {
  Activo (1),
  Inactivo (0);

  private final int activo;  
  
  ArticuloStatus(int value){
    activo = value;   
  }
  
  public int value(){
      return activo;
  }

  public String toString(){
     return Integer.toString(activo);
  }
}
```

Y acceder al valor como `ArticuloStatus.Activo.value()` por ejemplo

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/enum.html

Comment: Ahí debajo, en la misma documentación, está el ejemplo con los planetas y da un ejemplo que sí responde a la pregunta. Resumen, sí se puede

Comment: El segundo ejemplo DEBERÍA implementar los getters porque los atributos son privados. Pues, como para poder usarlos